# How to aggregate time-series data?

Tags: time-series, classification

I have two types of short length time series data (from day1-day5) as follows.

**Type1 (Temperature at location1):**

```
sensor1, 38, 38, 35, 33, 32
sensor2, 33, 32, 35, 36, 32
and so on ....
```

**Type2 (Temperature at location2):**

```
sensor1, 18, 18, 12, 11, 09
sensor2, 13, 12, 15, 16, 12
and so on ....
```

Since, the sensor that we use in both locations are same, I am just wondering if it is correct to aggregate the two time-series as follows and anaylyse the pattrens.

**Aggregation of Type1 and Type2:**

```
sensor1, 38, 38, 35, 33, 32, 18, 18, 12, 11, 09
sensor2, 33, 32, 35, 36, 32, 13, 12, 15, 16, 12
and so on ....
```

The reason why I thought to aggregate the data is that I thought it would give me more patterns than analysing them alone.

Please let me know your thoughts.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: If you paste them columnwise, you are pretending `sensor1:location1` is the same as `sensor1:location2`. You would also be ignoring the temporal structure, unless all measurements at `location2` were performed after those at `location1`, which would be an unfortunate study design. You should probably read into spatiotemporal autocorrelation using mixed models, or maybe vector autoregression, but it is hard to say as you've provided no clear research question or goal other than to find patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to the first comment, I would recommend you to have it as channels. i.e. whole data becomes 3 dimensional, which can be still processed by deep learning models.

Let me put it clear,

Dimension 1 - rows

Dimension 2 - Sensors

Dimension 3 - Location

so your data will look something like this

```
[[[38, 38, 35, 33, 32],
  [18, 18, 12, 11, 09]],
 [[33, 32, 35, 36, 32],
  [13, 12, 15, 16, 12]]]
```

This way it will make more sense to the model as well.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. I am new to deep learning. It would be really great if you could show me how I can insert such data to a deep-learning based binary classification problem :)

Comment: how you have your data ? Do you have in csv, text files or consuming from an API ?

Comment: I have my data in a csv file as `sensor1, 38, 38, 35, 33, 32
sensor2, 33, 32, 35, 36, 32` :)

Comment: okay. Hope you are using python. You can ignore the text containing sensor, and read the data as whole. Hopefully the number of values from each sensor are same. You can reshape them using numpy. 

for example, if it is like a=[1,2,3,4] and if you use numpy reshape function to make it a multi dimensional array as [[1,2][3,4]]  by using np.reshape(a,(2,-1))

Comment: please let me know your thoughts on this question: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/55752/how-to-input-data-to-lstmautoencoder

Comment: Hi, I looked at the other question, if you are planning to use LSTM, then the data can't have multiple channels. So you dont need to reshape. So basically your data will become of shape (num_samples, timesteps, features)  where features is 10 now, 5+5. Since yours is a binary classification, i dont think there will be a problem in giving them as a single sequence.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96238/discussion-between-venkat-krishnan-and-emj).

Comment: please check the chat. thank you :)